# How do I get a list with top 5 and then all the others as the 6'th item in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table that stores a line each time a team scores a goal:

```
| id | time |  team  | level |
------------------------------
|  1 | #### | Team 1 |   A   |
|  2 | #### | Team 2 |   B   |
...
```

I'm trying to get top 5 teams on level A with most goals and then combine all the rest as the 6th item in the list, like this:

```
|   team  |  goals |
-------------------
|  Team 1 |   13   |
|  Team 5 |   12   |
| Team 34 |    9   |
|  Team 7 |    7   |
| Team 19 |    7   |
|  Other  |   54   |
```

How do I get this? I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT team, goals
FROM (
    SELECT team, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS goals 
    FROM goals
    WHERE level = A
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY goals DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS g

UNION ALL
```

So this gives me the top 5, but I don't know how to make the second part which is the "other", because it has to exclude the teams from the top 5...

Comment: `WHERE level = A` so you needn't the `CASE ..level = A..`

Comment: @Serg That's correct but that has nothing to do with what I'm asking...

Comment: What about ties? I see that top #4 and #5 have both 7 goals. What if there are three more teams with 7 goals? Do you pick two arbitrarily or do you show all five, thus getting top 8 teams plus others? Or how else do you deal with this?

Comment: If there are ties they should just be picked arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study also the case of equality sum of goals in TOP-5 teams.
See functions ROW_NUMBER(),  RANK() and DENSE_RANK()

```
SELECT team
     , SUM(goal_total) goal_total
  FROM
     (
SELECT CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) <=5
       THEN team
       ELSE 'Other'
       END
       AS team
     , CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) <=5
       THEN ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc)
       ELSE 6
       END
       AS place
     , COUNT(*)
       AS goal_total
  FROM goals
 WHERE level = 'A'
 GROUP 
    BY team
     )
 GROUP
    BY team
     , place
 ORDER
    BY place
```

Comment: Note that `[level]` is an invalid identifier in standard SQL and Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, that's not a problem, itøs just dummy data.

Comment: The solution returns the correct result. Only problem is that I don't want the place column out.. is it possible to remove it but still kep the order?

Comment: fixed, "place" removed
Sorry, [column] - this is mssql-server

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your teams. Use `CASE WHEN` for the groups:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN team ELSE 'others' END AS team, sum(goals) as goals
FROM (
    SELECT 
      team, 
      COUNT(*) AS goals,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM goals
    WHERE level = 'A'
    GROUP BY team
) AS g
GROUP BY CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN team ELSE 'others' END
ORDER BY MAX(rn);
```

Comment: You were right, you cannot use `ROW_NUMBER` inside `GROUP BY`. I took the liberty to replace your query with an amended one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #temp(team varchar(50),goal int)
insert into #temp 
SELECT team, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS goals 
    FROM goals
    WHERE level = A
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY goals DESC
    LIMIT 5

    select team,goal from #temp

    union all

    SELECT team, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN level = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS goals 
    FROM goals g
    WHERE level = A
    and not exists (select 1 from #temp t where g.team=t.team)
    GROUP BY team
    --ORDER BY goals DESC

    drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the aggregate and the window function it could be a bit shorter

```
SELECT case rn when 6 then 'others' else team end gteam, sum(goals) goals
FROM (
    SELECT team, count(*) goals, 
         least(6, row_number() over(order by count(*))) rn
    FROM goals
    WHERE level = A
    GROUP BY team
) t
GROUP BY gteam, rn
ORDER BY rn
```